# Why does App Engine return at 404 when starting a version?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am playing around with `manual_scaling` on a module of mine because it only needs to be run once/day (it's a basic cron job) and App Engine spins up multiple instances that I don't need.

The way it will work is I plan on having a second cron job that starts my version with

```
from google.appengine.api import modules
[other code here]
def get(self):
    modules.start_version('downloader','one')
```

For whatever reason, when I do this, App Engine returns a 404:

```
INFO     2014-05-25 17:14:10,598 module.py:639] downloader: "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Although when I try to load a script that's only part of the `downloader` module, it works fine (and conversely stops working after I run `modules.stop_version('downloader','one')`

Even though the start/stop functionality I'd like is working fine, am I doing something incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the system works fine in spite of the 404 errors.  But it is easy enough to get rid of them, if you would rather not see these errors: just supply a handler for the _ah/start request.   I made mine return a simple text message:

```
class Noop(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write('#done\n')

app.router.add((r'/_ah/start',Noop))  # silence gao errors
```